# Animating a div to the corners of the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div in the bottom right corner. Clicking to one of the corners, the div should move there through an animation. The problem seems to be that `left` and `top` properties are blocking their pairs. I could make it work without animation, but now I am stuck. You can try; it works if you move it to the left or top, but not backward.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rws95a1q/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="chatdiv" style="width:400px; height:260px; position: fixed; top:auto; left:auto;bottom:0px; right:0px; background-color: #FF9933" >
    </div>
    <input id="chatlefttopbtn" type="button" style="position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px"/>
    <input id="chatrighttopbtn" type="button" style="position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px"/>
    <input id="chatleftbottombtn" type="button" style="position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: 0px"/>
    <input id="chatrightbottombtn" type="button" style="position: fixed; right: 0px; bottom: 0px"/>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#chatdiv  {
    width:400px; 
    height:260px; 
    position: absolute !important; 
    top:auto;
    left:auto;
    bottom:0px; 
    right:0px; 
    background-color: #FF9933; 
}

#chatlefttopbtn {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;                  
}

#chatrighttopbtn {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;               
}

#chatleftbottombtn {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;               
}

#chatrightbottombtn {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;               
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var firstMove = true;

    $(function() { 
        document.getElementById("chatlefttopbtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        moveChatWindow("lefttop");
    }, false);

    document.getElementById("chatrighttopbtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        moveChatWindow("righttop");
    }, false);

    document.getElementById("chatleftbottombtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        moveChatWindow("leftbottom");
    }, false);

    document.getElementById("chatrightbottombtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        moveChatWindow("rightbottom");
    }, false);
    });

    function moveChatWindow(moveTo) {
    var chatWindow = $("#chatdiv");

    var left = chatWindow.offset().left;
    var right = ($(window).width() - (chatWindow.offset().left + chatWindow.outerWidth()));
    var top = chatWindow.offset().top; 
    var bottom = ($(window).height() - (chatWindow.offset().top + chatWindow.outerHeight()));

    if(firstMove){
        chatWindow.css({left:left, right: right, bottom: bottom, top: top});
        firstMove = false;
    }

    chatWindow.css.position = 'absolute';

    if(moveTo === "lefttop"){
        chatWindow.css.left = left;
        chatWindow.css.top = top;
        chatWindow.css.right = 0;
        chatWindow.css.bottom = 0;

        chatWindow.animate({
            left : '0px',
            top : '0px'
        }, 2000);
    } else if(moveTo === "righttop"){
        chatWindow.css.left = "auto";
        chatWindow.css.top = top;
        chatWindow.css.right = right;
        chatWindow.css.bottom = 0;

        chatWindow.animate({
            top : '0px',
            right : '0px'
        }, 2000);
    } else if(moveTo === "leftbottom"){
        chatWindow.css.top = 0;
        chatWindow.css.left = left;
        chatWindow.css.right = 0;
        chatWindow.css.bottom = bottom; 

        chatWindow.animate({
            left : '0px',
            bottom : '0px'
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        chatWindow.css.left = 0;
        chatWindow.css.top = 0;
        chatWindow.css.right = right;
        chatWindow.css.bottom = bottom;

        chatWindow.animate({
            right : '0px',
            bottom : '0px'
        }, 2000);   
    }
}
```

Note: This is not the real code, do not judge me, I just threw it together for the sake of the question.

Comment: In the future, please do not circumvent the rules for including a JSFiddle link (rules which require you to include your code directly in the question itself).

Comment: What a long code ! BEfore trying to find any solution, start by using four classes `topLeft` `topRight` `bottomLeft` and `bottomRight`. You shouldn't write all that CSS in the javascript but rather in these 4 classes. Then, with javascript you switch between these classes. And use Jquery methods such as `$("#chatrighttopbtn")` , much more clearer. When you are done with these changes I'll look at your problem.

Comment: quote myself: "Note: This is not the real code, do not judge me, I just threw it together for the sake of the question." If you may wonder, the reason is, the original code cannot be uploaded to a public website. Any further help, on this code would be nice.

Comment: I think you should do something with older positions, because in the end you're left with div who has all four positions: top:0px, right:0px, bottom:0px and left:0px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're assigning values to all four corners of the object: top, right, bottom and left.

To move this properly you only need to change 2 of the co-ordinates.

Because your chat window starts in the bottom right, we'll use that as our datum.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rws95a1q/4/**

Basic code:

```
var chatWindow = $("#chatdiv");
var chatWidth = chatWindow.width();
var chatHeight = chatWindow.height();

var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

function moveChatWindow(moveTo) {
    if (moveTo === "lefttop") {
        chatWindow.stop().animate({
             bottom: windowHeight - chatHeight
           , right: windowWidth - chatWidth
        }, 2000);
    }
    else if (moveTo === "righttop") {
        chatWindow.stop().animate({
             bottom: windowHeight - chatHeight
           , right: 0
        }, 2000);
    }
    else if (moveTo === "leftbottom") {
        chatWindow.stop().animate({
             bottom: 0
           , right: windowWidth - chatWidth
        }, 2000);
    }
    else {
        chatWindow.stop().animate({
             bottom: 0
           , right: 0
        }, 2000);
    }
```

First up we have to work out a few things - namely the dimensions of the chat box and the size of the document/window. This gives us enough data points to work out where to animate to.

Next comes the animation: note how the only dimensions we are ever assigning new values to are the **bottom** and **right**.

To set it to the "lefttop", the **bottom** of the chat window needs to be 260px from the top, which is equivalent to the height of the document minus the height of the chat box. The principal for **left** is the same: width of the document minus the chat box width.

UPDATE: I would probably change the positioning of the chat box to fixed. Alternatively I have included some extra code in the JSFiddle to handle window resizing (in principal).

Comment: Well, after some testing, i marked this as the answer, using ID swapping, would have required a lot of code changes from me, in the original one. Thanks for this answer, i could easily merge it with my own code!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not what you asked for specifically, but here is a solution using css transitions for animations (you will need to add prefixes for transition).

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rws95a1q/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="chatdiv"></div>
<input id="chatlefttopbtn" type="button" />
<input id="chatrighttopbtn" type="button" />
<input id="chatleftbottombtn" type="button" />
<input id="chatrightbottombtn" type="button" />
```

CSS:

```
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
.chatdiv  {
    width:400px; 
    height:260px; 
    background-color: #FF9933;
    transition: margin .5s;
}
#topleft{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#topright{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: calc(100% -  400px);
}
#bottomleft{
    margin-top: calc(100% -  260px);
    margin-left: 0;
}
#bottomright{
    margin-top: calc(100% -  260px);
    margin-left: calc(100% -  400px);
}
#chatlefttopbtn {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;                  
}

#chatrighttopbtn {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;               
}

#chatleftbottombtn {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;               
}

#chatrightbottombtn {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;               
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$("#chatlefttopbtn").click(function(){
    $(".chatdiv").attr("id","topleft");
});
$("#chatrighttopbtn").click(function(){
    $(".chatdiv").attr("id","topright");
});
$("#chatrightbottombtn").click(function(){
    $(".chatdiv").attr("id","bottomright");
});
$("#chatleftbottombtn").click(function(){
    $(".chatdiv").attr("id","bottomleft");
});
```

Comment: It doens't stick to the very bottom of the page when one of the buttons on the bottom is clicked. But I do applaud your CSS3 approach!

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure out why that bit doesn't work. Maybe it's an iframe problem. Not too familiar with iframes.

Comment: Well this is a better solution, then the one i intended. Thanks, I am more than satisfied with this one!